# Where is Corruption chasm or any corruption area?

Tags: terraria

I saw a few pictures of the Corruption area on Wikis and forums and started to search for that in my world.
I covered from cost to cost and couldn't find it.
After opening the world in the TEdit to search for it, again, I couldn't find it.

Could you help me identify it on the picture attached to this question?
Note: if you need a better zoom on the picture, let me know.

[image: Terraria world]

Comment: You're pretty lucky, your crimsons generated right next to each other. This should make containing it before hardmode much easier.

Comment: I'm in the learning process right now. I just started to play it. So, thanks for the good news!  The sad thing is not knowing what to do next. That is really annoying.

Comment: If you have defeated the eye of Cthulhu, I suggest you then get good armour and tools then kill the brain of Cthulhu. Next would be some of the mini bosses like the queen bee and the king slime (these aren't necessary for game advancement). Then defeat Skeletron, and explore your dungeon until you have good tools and a shadow key. Then, dig a hellevator (a large tunnel to the bottom of the world), loot the shadow chests, make a long bridge across the entirety of the underworld and defeat the Wall of Flesh. That should keep you busy until you reach hardmode. The wiki is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have one.  You have a Crimson area, that starts on the west side of your snow biome.

Crimson is a different version of Corruption, and you have either one or the other in any given world.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the Eater of Worlds? I thought I would need shadow orbs or worm food found in the corrupt area. How am I suppose to get those? Are they available in the Crimson area?

Comment: @vianna77 - nope, they are not, and neither is the Eater of Worlds.  There is however, corresponding items (hearts instead of orbs, for one), to summon the Crimson's boss, which is Brain of Cthulu.

Comment: @vianna77 - If you need/want Eater of Worlds for some particular reason, you can either generate a new world for that purpose, or try setting it up artificially, as detailed in the other answer here.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm starting to understand how Terraria works. So, after Eye of Cthulu, the next boss would be the Crimson one, right?

Comment: @vianna77 - For the world you're in, yep.  Although you may want to edit that into your question if that's what you were leading towards, Q&A like this in comments usually gets removed eventually.

Comment: I will remove my questions here in the comment and move it to the main question. Thanks again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29063/discussion-between-vianna77-and-radhil).

Answer (score 2):

Taken directly from the [Corruption page on Terraria's wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/The_Corruption):

> The corruption is the counterpart to the Crimson biome. A generated world will contain only one of the two, chosen at random during world creation, each with a 50% chance of occurring.

Just past your ice biome you have a [Crimson biome](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson). Instead of fighting the Eater of Worlds, you get to fight the [Brain of Cthulu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu).

Despite not having any corruption in your world, it is possible to create artificial corruption biomes. Generate new worlds until you find one with corruption in it instead of Crimson. Once you do, defeat the Eye of Cthulu. It will drop several corrupt seeds you can use to plant in your original world.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking that my game was somewhat corrupted. I mean, how am I suppose to fight a boss that cannot be summoned? :) Now I'm starting to understand how it works!